# PHP tree ancestry check

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I have a database with Groups, each group can contain other groups and so on.
The structure of the database is Like this:

```
 Group[Id,Name]
 GroupGroups[Id,ParentGroup,ChildGroup]
```

I want to check before adding a group to a parent if  it group is already in the upper levels.
What would be the best approach?
I can think in having a cache with all the ancestries of each node in each context, or building the tree and travessing it to the root to check if the added element isn't already there.

Comment: You might want to check out nested set model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Have a look at Joe Celko's *Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties* http://store.elsevier.com/Joe-Celkos-Trees-and-Hierarchies-in-SQL-for-Smarties/Joe-Celko/isbn-9780123877338/.  It's an excellent reference.

Comment: My tree have nodes that will be repeated in other places, does you know if this particular type of tree has a specific name or if the book have a section about this case?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what you're asking. Do you mean that there is more than one path to a particular node?  If so, you don't have a tree, you have a graph and nested sets won't work.

Comment: I hadn't think about it, but now that you mentioned the strutcture of the data couldn't be a tree, thanks for your time it really helped

Comment: Are you saying that a single group can have multiple parents? If every group can only have only one (or zero) parents, then you have a tree.

Comment: One group can be a child of several other groups.I guess you can see it as several distinct trees (as any group can only be on the tree once ). A group can be a member of several trees